# Como deixar a fonte da linha selecionada em negrito no DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

No DataGridView do Windows Forms é possível mudar a cor da fonte e a cor de fundo da linha selecionada facilmente usando as propriedades

```
DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor
DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor
```

Mas e para deixar a linha selecionada com a fonte em negrito? Eu já tentei algumas coisas como usar o evento `SelectionChanged` da seguinte forma:

```
private void Grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataGridView = Grid;

    if (dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        var selectedRow = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0];
        selectedRow.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }            
}
```

Acontece que isso deixa sempre todas as linhas com a fonte em negrito, então não é bem por aí.

Qual é o jeito certo de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta algo assim:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
  if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected)
  {
    e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Coral;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Você já tentou utilizar as propriedades do Grid ?

Senão:
Clique em cima do Grid depois procure na aba properties que fica do lado direito, as propriedades **RowDefaultCellStyle** ou **RowTemplate** que talvez resolva seu problema. Assim você não precisa deixar de forma dinâmica no seu código. As próprias propriedades do objeto já fazem isso para você.